# Provided dependencies using Gradle (JetGradle) and Intellij Idea 13

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a multiproject build with multiple war modules that depends on one jar module.

Both war and jar modules have dependencies over libraries like Spring, Hibernate and so on, those dependencies are defined as providedCompile on the war modules and as compile on the jar.

The problem is that when JetGradle updates the dependencies all artifacts have errors, as the dependencies from the jar module are required on the artifacts.

I would like to use any of this solutions:

1. Include the libraries on the lib folder of the server and have Intellij treat them as provided.
2. Include the libraries as project wide libraries somehow, so intellij puts them on all artifacts even after the gradle dependencies are updated.

On the other hand my approach could be completely wrong from the beginning.

The dependencies in the war modules are defined as:

```
providedCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
providedCompile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5'
...
compile(project(':jarModule')) {transitive = false}
...
```

The dependencies in the jar module are defined as:

```
...
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5'
...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best solution I found was to set the transitive "compile" dependencies from the jar module as provided using the following code in the Gradle configuration file:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

configurations {
    provided
    provided.extendsFrom(compile)
}

idea {
    module {
        scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.provided
    }
}
```

**For Gradle 2.0+** modify the last bit to be like this:

```
idea {
    module {
        scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]
    }
}
```

This solution works using the Intellij Gradle plugin and also the idea task in Gradle

I got this solution working based on the info on this urls:
https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/pull/145
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html

I hope this helps someone else

Comment: When using Gradle 2.0 or higher it must be `scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]`. See http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_2_0_idea_plugin_adding_a_custom_configuration_to_scope_throws_classcastexception

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, I'm going to update the answer to reflect that

Comment: The error message one will encounter (without using the square brackets) is "you cannot modify the provided scope because it has already been resolved!".

Comment: Well, if I use this approach then all dependencies in the "provided" configuration will not get into the "compile" configuration. As a result, although IDEA sees them correctly, it is no longer possible to build the library JAR using gradle only (without IDEA). What am I missing?

Comment: I used this approach to run in intellij the application war that includes the  "jarModule" I have created but excludes all of it's dependencies (this dependencies would be included on the Tomcat lub folder. In my case it didn't affect the gradle normal build process, however I'm not using this approach any more so I cannot confirm if this still works with the newest versions of the software.

Comment: I am getting an error `Cannot get property 'plus' on null object`

Comment: Are you sure you added `provided` on the `configurations` block?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution but found a problem. In my scenario I had a sub-project that had the above configuration. The problem was that the transitive dependencies of the sub-project were not being exported in the IntelliJ configuration, which caused the base project to stop compiling.

I did some digging around and stumbled upon this little gem which fixed the problem.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/ccddc438ce09293d84030ebe31668d739c8a228a/gradle/providedConfiguration.gradle

```
/**
 * Adds a configuration named 'provided'. 'Provided' dependencies
 * are incoming compile dependencies that aren't outgoing
 * dependencies. In other words, they have no effect on transitive
 * dependency management.
 */

configurations {
    provided
    providedPlusCompile.extendsFrom(compile, provided)
    testCompile.extendsFrom(providedPlusCompile)
}

sourceSets.main {
    compileClasspath = configurations.providedPlusCompile
}

plugins.withType(IdeaPlugin) {
    idea.module.scopes.PROVIDED.plus = [ configurations.provided ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer from Adrijardi, for **Gadle 2.0 +** not only did I have to change

```
scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.provided
```

to

```
scopes.PROVIDED.plus += [configurations.provided]
```

I also had to change

```
provided project(":module-name") {
    transitive = false
}
```

to

```
provided (project(":module-name")) {
    transitive = false
}
```

Note the extra set of brackets on the second code sample