# Custom artifact generation on Intellij Idea 13 and Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using the Intellij Idea 13 Gradle plugin and I'd like to modify the default artifact creation.

The problem I face is that my war modules have dependencies on 3rd party libraries that I don't want to include in the war itself, however I would like to include them in the Intellij artifact so they are deployed to my local server for testing.

At the moment I'm getting errors of the type `Artifact ... library required for module is missing from the artifact`.

What would be the best way to tell Intellij to add those libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the way to add those libraries, but I've found the way to set them as provided so they can be added to the server lib folder.

The solution is detailed here: [Provided dependencies using Gradle (JetGradle) and Intellij Idea 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421681/provided-dependencies-using-gradle-jetgradle-and-intellij-idea-13)